# How can I go through each link on a page and append something with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of links on a page that on an action, I run a function and it appends an extra variable like so:

```
function storeId(uID) {
    $('a.special').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '&variable=' + uID + '');
    });
}
```

My understanding is, the above would go through each link identified, and grab the existing href, then append the variable bits onto the end. I have got the variable appending, but its not working as expected... e.g its appending the '&variable=' part twice, the first time, like '&variable=undefined' and then on top of that '&variable=23'.

Is there a better way to do this? Or a way I can just say go through each of these links and simply update the value that is set to the variable rather than rewriting the whole href?

So just to re-iterate, my original link is just something like this:

```
<a class="special" href="/page.php?random=1">link name</a>
```

And the aim is to have it look like the following after the function is performed:

```
<a class="special" href="/page.php?random=1&variable=32">link name</a>
```

But it winds up looking like:

```
<a class="special" href="/page.php?random=1&variable=undefined&variable=32">link name</a>
```

Comment: are you sure that storeID isn't getting called twice?   seems like it is.

Comment: thats what I was thinking... maybe it is!!

Comment: yet you gave the answer to someone else?  my karma hangs in the balance. :)

Comment: lol... i would have given you the answer... but you commented, not answered!! write an answer and I will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that storeId isn't getting called twice? seems like it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
function storeId(uID) {
    $('a.special').each(function(){
        link = $(this).attr('href');
        nlink = link + '&variable='+uID;
        $(this).attr('href', newlink);
    });
}
```

Give that a try.

Comment: not exactly - he has unescaped quotes inside the second .attr call.